# Sencha Architect 3 Android Simulation failed

Tags: ant, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I just want to look at sencha architect 3 and created the Touch 2.3 project "locations". Starting Web and simulation in iOS works great, but native Android build failed:

```
[INF] -before-native-package:
[INF] 
[INF] -native-package-mobile:
[INF]      [echo] Running default mobile packager config.
[INF]      [echo] 
[INF]      [echo]     Processing Mobile Packager config file
[INF]      [echo]         config: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/packager.json
[INF]      [echo]         inputPath: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native/MyApp
[INF]      [echo]         outputPath: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json
[INF]      [echo] Running mobile packager action run on file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/packager.temp.json
[ERR] 
Error: Project folder '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json' is not empty. Please consider using 'android update' instead.
Created directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/src/com/mycompany/myAppID
Added file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/src/com/mycompany/myAppID/STActivity.java
Created directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/res
Created directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/bin
Created directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/libs
Created directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/res/values
Added file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/res/values/strings.xml
Created directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/res/layout
Added file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/res/layout/main.xml
Added file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/AndroidManifest.xml
Added file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/build.xml
Added file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/proguard-project.txt
sh: ant: command not found
"/Users/markus/android-sdks/tools/android" create project --target android-7 --name MyApp --activity STActivity --path "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/build/native-package-mobile/MyApp/packager.json/" --package com.mycompany.myAppID
Could not run ant with error: 32512
Failed to package application

[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Nati
[ERR] veMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 7 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:108: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:98: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:7: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Run a

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant

this will make Architect 3 detect your installation.

This is if you are using a Mac and installed your ant using homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Ant is not installed.

I had the same issue.  I assume you're on a Mac since you say iOS worked.  Apparently in Mavericks, ant is no longer included by default.

you can install it with homebrew easily enough.

However, that still does not work for me.  Here's a help thread I started on the sencha architect forums:  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?277937-Simple-attempt-at-an-android-build&p=1017898#post1017898